# Правильно ли поставлены знаки? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

***Не знаю, была ли я рада за него, наверное, да.***

Comment: Вместо второй запятой нужна точка. А лучше — многоточие...

Answer (score 1):

Правильно так:

`Не знаю, была ли я рада за него. Наверное, да.`

или

`Не знаю, была ли я рада за него... Наверное, да.` (это лучше)